# Edit Checkbox Question Label with CSS and/or Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to change the label for a checkbox question. I don't have access to the HTML, so I am stuck using CSS and/or Javascript.

I would like to replace the original label **This donation is on behalf of a company** with **Organization Name**.

I tried using the CSS code below, but it just added the replacement text before the original text (see the images at the bottom). The code worked for changing text field labels, but doesn't seem to work with the checkbox label.

```css
label[for="is_donating_company"] {
  font-size: 0 !important;
}

label[for="is_donating_company"]:before {
  content: "Organization Name";
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-js-ripple-effect--ignore-events is-upgraded" for="is_donating_company" data-upgraded=",MaterialCheckbox,MaterialRipple" style="height: 24px;">
<input type="checkbox" name="is_donating_company" id="is_donating_company" class="mdl-checkbox__input">
<span class="mdl-checkbox__label">This donation is on behalf of a company</span>
<span class="mdl-checkbox__focus-helper"></span><span class="mdl-checkbox__box-outline">
<span class="mdl-checkbox__tick-outline"></span></span>
<span class="mdl-checkbox__ripple-container mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-ripple--center" data-upgraded=",MaterialRipple">
<span class="mdl-ripple"></span></span>
</label>
```

Images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSJXo.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4X8e.png

Comment: please add your html too, this is unsolvable provided with only this information

Comment: I just added it!

Comment: I am trying to replace the original label 'This donation is on behalf of a company' with 'Organization Name'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution for your case that depends only on CSS:

```css
label[for="is_donating_company"] span.mdl-checkbox__label { font-size: 0 !important; }
label[for="is_donating_company"] span.mdl-checkbox__label:after { content: "Organization Name"; font-size: 16px; }
```

```html
<label for="is_donating_company">
  <input type="checkbox" name="is_donating_company" id="is_donating_company" class="mdl-checkbox__input">
  <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">This donation is on behalf of a company</span>
</label>
```